# TinyMCE editor inside a TinyMCE Plugin

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I am creating a plugin for TinyMCE, which is basically a form that has a textarea in it. I want the user to be able to input formatted text in that textarea, using the TinyMCE editor. The problem is that I'm not able to 'enrich' the textarea element inside the dialog.htm file in any way. Does there exist a way to do such a thing?

Thanks in advance,

Tomor

Comment: What's the problem. What have you tried so far ? If we put aside that it seem a really weird idea and may cause layout issues, I don't see why technically it would be a problem so instanciate a TinyMCE editor in TinyMCE... it's all DOM elements !

Comment: @FMaz008 I have tried calling the tinyMCE.init() inside the dialog.htm, with these parameters: 'mode: exact, elements: el1' as the id of the element is 'el1'. I have also put this call inside $(document).ready().

Comment: I have tried putting another parameter inside init(), called onInit: test, which calls the test function, which merely prints a message in the console, and it seems that the function is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quick fix. I managed to put the editor in an iframe, following the suggestion in this post:

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=84668#p84668

It seems a bit messy, but it works.